# How to extend event types in eventemitter generic?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Here is small example extracted from project:

```js
import { EventEmitter } from 'eventemitter3';

type AnyObject = Record<string, any>;

enum EEvent {
    AudioVolume = "AudioVolume",
    Response = "Response"
}

interface DefaultResponse {
    test: number;
}

export interface EventsAndPayload<ServerResponseGamePart extends AnyObject> {
    [EEvent.AudioVolume]: [number];
    [EEvent.Response]: [ServerResponseGamePart];
}

export class CoreEventEmitter<
    ServerResponse extends DefaultResponse,
    // CustomEvents extends AnyObject            <------ added this
> extends EventEmitter<
    // CustomEvents                              <------ trying to merge here
    & EventsAndPayload<ServerResponse>
> {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.emit(EEvent.AudioVolume, 5) // <----- types might be broken here if "&" used
    }
}

const emitter = new CoreEventEmitter();

emitter.on(EEvent.Response, (response) => {  // <----- or here (response) if "|" used
    console.log(response.test, 'is a number');
});

emitter.emit(EEvent.AudioVolume, 5);
```

I want to be able to pass events as generic type so that `EventsAndPayload` will be extended. I've added second type called `CustomEvents`.

- I've tried to merge them with `&`, but in this case `this.emit` inside classes looses types.
- I've tried to merge them with `|`, but in this case types lost inside `.on` callbacks.
- Also tried to extend from `EventsAndPayload<ServerResponse>` instead of `AnyObject`, but it also not work.

What I am doing wrong?